# What is the difference between introducing separated fixed effects (i.e. country FE + sector FE) and interacted fixed effects (i.e. country-sector FE)

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, fixed-effects-model

Assume I have data at the country ($c$)-sector ($s$)- firm ($i$) level. I can introduce separated country and sector fixed effects, or I can introduce country-sector fixed effects, as shown in the two equations below.

$$Y_{csi}=X_{csi}\beta+\alpha_{c}+\lambda_{s} + \epsilon_{csi}$$

$$Y_{csi}=X_{csi}\beta+\theta_{cs} + \epsilon_{csi}$$

I would welcome the chance to understand **what assumptions are made in each case, and hence understand why they are different.** The second model seems more restricticve, but I cannot clearly explain why.

Thanks!

Comment: The first model is most restrictive. If it is correct it gives more precise estimates.

Comment: See also this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466607/what-is-the-difference-between-region-year-and-region-year-fixed-effects/466760#466760

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out.